# Icon for website

Tags: icons, internet

I'm looking for a good universal icon for **website**

Here are a few I found, but looking for something better:

[image: Examples from Icon8 (which is great!)]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by “better”? How are you measuring better?

Comment: A larger % of english speaking humans would identify that as "website" if they saw it.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following work for you? They're pretty self explanatory I think:

1. [First Icon](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic.thenounproject.com%2Fpng%2F63346-200.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fthenounproject.com%2Fterm%2Fwebsite%2F1689581%2F&docid=R3hWt2h_pkPe8M&tbnid=ltE6i8y4W0M6oM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwiEjoi7wq_fAhUFbn0KHQTQAMYQMwiYASgmMCY..i&w=200&h=200&bih=1049&biw=1920&q=website%20icon&ved=0ahUKEwiEjoi7wq_fAhUFbn0KHQTQAMYQMwiYASgmMCY&iact=mrc&uact=8)
2. [Second Icon](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn4.iconfinder.com%2Fdata%2Ficons%2Fweb-pages-seo%2F512%2F33-512.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.iconfinder.com%2Ficons%2F374457%2Faddress_http_web_web_page_webpage_website_icon&docid=_BXLoTgz2PvWfM&tbnid=xravEi6r_Qu7BM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwiEjoi7wq_fAhUFbn0KHQTQAMYQMwhtKAgwCA..i&w=512&h=512&bih=1049&biw=1920&q=website%20icon&ved=0ahUKEwiEjoi7wq_fAhUFbn0KHQTQAMYQMwhtKAgwCA&iact=mrc&uact=8)

[image]

[image]